# Is this a good Stack Exchange site (or is there one) for questions about the Samsung Gear S3?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've recently purchased a [Samsung Gear S3](http://www.samsung.com/us/explore/gear-s3/) smartwatch, and already I have some questions I'd like to ask of experienced users.

However:

1. I am aware that the watch's OS is Tizen-based, not Android.
2. My current questions have nothing to do with the watch connecting to an Android device. (In fact, my current phone, until the Galaxy S8 comes out, is still Windows-based and the watch is presently in Standalone mode.)

Considering that the watch seems primarily to target Android users (though it does support iOS), I expect there is a certain audience among this site who would be interested in and knowledgeable of the device. However, since it is not actually an Android-based device itself, I am not sure that questions which are solely about the Gear S3 would really be on-topic here.

Could someone please point me in the right direction for where questions about this watch would be on-topic within Stack Exchange, if such a site exists?

Sample question (currently the only one I have in mind):

> "Can I change the time display format for the built-in digital watch faces on my Gear S3?"

Comment: For anyone who runs into the display format issue I mentioned: It seems the fix requires Bluetooth pairing to a supported phone. (At the time of my original post, I was using a Windows Phone which is unsupported.) Once the watch is paired to a phone, it seems to automatically follow the phone's display settings - thus, if the phone is set to use a 24-hour time format, the Gear will do so as well for digital faces.

Answer (score 7):

We only support questions about non-Android devices inasmuch as they relate to using them with Android.  So your point #2 disqualifies you from asking here.

I do not believe there is a current SE site where you could ask your question; we no longer have a generalized Gadgets site for devices/OSes that don't have the critical mass for their own site.

Comment: Regarding a "Gadgets" site: I did find [iot.se] but I don't think that's quite the right fit either.

Comment: "we no longer have a generalized Gadgets site" - so we did in the past? Curious about its fate.

Comment: @AndyYan According to its [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) the beta didn't gather enough activity, so it was closed. Appropriately-tagged questions were migrated to [android.se] and [apple.se]. It was also mentioned in a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/14/pruning-season/).

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61593/21960

Answer (score 1):

As much as I prefer such questions to ones about WhatsApp usage (duh), off-topic is off-topic.

For device-specific questions I'd look at XDA-Developers before here. They do have a [Gear S3 subforum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/gear-s3), where you could ask such questions without restrictions, although the chance of getting an answer is debatable.

Comment: Or try Reddit, they'll always lend a helpful hand.